# Display die(); message on the same page as form

Tags: php, die

I am a beginner with PHP.

Anyway, I have this form:

```
<form method="post" action="mail.php" id="contactform">
    <div class="stage cf">
        <input type="text" name="contactname" id="contactname" placeholder="Name" class="required" role="input" aria-required="true" />
    </div>
    <div class="stage cf">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="useremail" placeholder="Email" class="required email" role="input" aria-required="true" />
    </div>
    <div class="stage cf">
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" class="required" role="input" aria-required="true" />
    </div>
    <div class="stage cf">
        <textarea rows="5" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" class="required" role="textbox" aria-required="true"></textarea>
    </div>                                      
        <input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit" id="submitButton" title="SendMessage" />
    <div id="response"></div>
</form>
```

When the form is sent, I want to display a die message on the same page. The message at this point shows on another page.

This chunk of my `mail.php` file sends the mail:

```
//If there is no error, send the email
if(!isset($hasError)) {
    $emailTo = 'test@randommail.com'; //Put your own email address here
    $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nSubject: $subject \n\nComments:\n $comments";
    $headers = "From: $email";

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $emailSent = true;

}
die("<span class='success'>Success! Your message has been sent.</span>");
```

and this Ajax should do the trick:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $("#send").attr("value", "Sending...");
    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
        success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
            $(form).slideUp("fast");
            $("#response").html(responseText).hide().slideDown("fast");
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If the Ajax works, why not use it?

Comment: I think you need to use the `error:` callback to get the response when the script dies.

Comment: @Hope4You, i have this AJAX code i mentioned in my .js files, but it doesn't work for some reason o.O? That's what i need help with.

Answer (score 1):

die('string') means, stop running and dump the 'string'
It should work!

Comment: The die() function display the string that is given to it, but it displays on a new page, and i would like to display it on the page where the form is.

Answer (score 0):

it is the same page (mail.php) but you are calling die before the html is displayed so move your die line after the html code